# Regex function to check the presence of any letter on the string or only number or symbols

Tags: php, regex

I'm a little confused about the usage of regular expression in all the entry string.

I need to understand if a given string contain any number or symbols, or viceversa don't contain any letters:

| good | no good |
| --- | --- |
| ! |  |
| - 1 - |  |
| => |  |
|  | foo |
|  | foo bar |
| { |  |
|  | I have 3 bananas |
| 123 456 |  |

So I need something like that `/[^A-Za-z]/` but in the strign I have **3** bananas the `preg_math_full` is fired, how can I use the regex pattern in all the string??

Comment: Do you mean you need `^[a-zA-Z\s]*$`?

Comment: To clarify your criteria, _the string should not have an `a-z` character? And any punctuation and/or numbers only are fine?

Comment: @MarkusAO yes, I need to delete all the string that don't contain any A-Z a-z the way of Wictor is good, I just neeeded to remove the \s cause a space between number is accepted

Comment: A string contains no letters if it matches `^(?!.*[a-zA-Z])`, `(?!.*[a-zA-Z])` being a *negative lookahead*.

Comment: It is not still clear, could you please provide two arrays: one input array and the other expected output array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude letters, you can simply search for `[a-z]` and reverse the result, such as :

```
$testArray = [
    "!",
    "- 1 -",
    "=>",
    "foo",
    "foo bar",
    "{",
    "I have 3 bananas",
    "123 456"
];

foreach ($testArray as $element)
{
    echo "$element is ";
    //  v--- check this
    if (!preg_match("#[a-z]#i", $element))
    {
        echo "good" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not good" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This will output :

```
! is good
- 1 - is good
=> is good
foo is not good
foo bar is not good
{ is good
I have 3 bananas is not good
123 456 is good
```

[Fiddle](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/1bfae)